# Return underlying value of boost::variant with boost::apply_visitor

Tags: c++, boost

Is it possible to code the write the `boost:static_visitor` so that it could return the underlying value of a `boost::variant` in a type-safe way?
My current efforts to do that look as follows.

```
using EventData = boost::variant<boost::blank, int, std::string, boost::system::error_code>;

struct EventDataVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<> 
{
  int operator()(int number) const { return number; }
  SstErrors operator()(SstErrors err) const { return err; }
  boost::blank operator()(boost::blank) const { return boost::blank{}; }
  decltype(auto) operator()(const boost::system::error_code& ec) const { return ec; }
};
```

Next, I want to use the `EventData` variant as follows:

```
EventData data {"Hello world!"};
// ... Some code here ...

// Retrieve data of specific type later. 
// Should safely return the underlying value of a type it was initialized with.
std::string& eventDataString = boost::apply_visitor(EventDataVisitor{}, data)
```

If this is not possible, what is another safe way to retrieve the current value of the `EventData`? (With or better without enabling RTTI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If that were possible you wouldn't need variant.

Another way of putting it: you **can** but it requires you to return (another) variant, e.g.:

```
struct EventDataVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<boost::variant<boost::blank, int, SstErrors, boost::system::error_code> >
{
  int operator()(int number) const { return number; }
  SstErrors operator()(SstErrors err) const { return err; }
  boost::blank operator()(boost::blank) const { return boost::blank{}; }
  decltype(auto) operator()(const boost::system::error_code& ec) const { return ec; }
};
```

The usual approach is to pass a callback that is invoked with the active element type. This is exactly what the visitor interface is, but sometimes it might make sense to have a more specific interface.

> If this is not possible, what is another safe way to retrieve the current value of the EventData? (With or better without enabling RTTI).

```
 EventData data {"Hello world!"};
 std::string& eventDataString = boost::get<std::string>(data);
```

That's safe. If there's more between the assignment and use, you might use the pointer versions of `get<>`:

```
 if (auto* p = boost::get<std::string>(&data)) {
      // contains a valid std::string
      std::string& eventDataString = *p;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! My main aim was to prevent putting one type into `EventData`, while trying to get a different type using `boost::get`. For instance, a developer may forget that they previously put `std::string` into `EventData` and now try to get `int`. Those errors will be detected only at runtime. I wanted to detect such errors at a compile time. If I understand correctly, I can achieve this using `apply_visitor` and passing a callback to it that will do data processing. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. You can also use the method shown in my answer (pointer-get). I assumed you understood the visitor approach because you show one in your question :)